# How Get Json in android

Tags: android, json, asp.net-mvc

[image]

I used Asp.net MVC to create an API and it returns JSON. Now I want to receive the JSON in my Android application, but I get an error.

I return `[{"id":22,"Name":"2","Family":"1"}]` and my browser shows this at http://192.168.1.100/api/people.

Here is my Android code:

```
public class RetrieveFormWebActivity extends Activity {

    private static String url = "http://192.168.1.100/api/people";

    //JSON Node Names
    JSONArray user = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        // Depends on your web service
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            // json is UTF-8 by default
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.i("re", result);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // Oops
        } finally {
            try {
                if (inputStream != null)
                    inputStream.close();
            }
            catch (Exception squish) {}
        }
    }
}
```

in log shows an error eccurred: why ?

Comment: `in log shows an error eccurred` which error ?? show logcat result when application crash

Comment: please some one help me

Comment: in log shows an error eccurred which error ?? show logcat result when application crash

Comment: please post full code and log as text instead of image

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByZRUdKjujQtRHhIVWdkQ0pZVFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94238/discussion-between-user3480060-and--k).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByZRUdKjujQtNnd6RW1DanFMNXM/view?usp=sharing        this is the log

Answer (score 0):

Getting `NPE`  due to:

```
....
TextView txts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
txts.setText(result); //<<<<
....
```

Line causing issue because `txts` is `null`.

Why `null`:

Because not calling `setContentView` method by passing layout id in which TextView with `txt` is available  in `onCreate`.

Do it as:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout_file_name);
    ... your code here
}
```

**NOTE:** Currenlty doing Network related task in Main UI Thread which will cause `ANR` dialog. so use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for doing network related jobs in background Thread.

Comment: it's not answer  i used now my textview and log.i how an error message occure my problem is get json not UI setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout_file_name);

Comment: @user3480060: dude. if you comment this `Log.i("resss", e.toString());` line then you will still get issue because program is going in catch block try/catch block due to `txts` is `null`. and if you know what is problem then why not fixing it instead of asking question?

Comment: excuse me sir .but i remove all textview if json posted in logcat must show me the json but shows an error eccurre why?

Comment: @user3480060: hmm as you can see yourself in this pic http://i.stack.imgur.com/wf79I.png getting NPE at tag `resss`

Comment: @user3480060: and where you are passing jsonobject?? why you are not providing full code from class?

Comment: did you have code that can get json from server that check it with it?

Answer (score 0):

Put all httprequests in a new thread. You cannot do httprequests in the ui thread.